# Calculation for extending a geo bounding box by x miles

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, geo

Hoping someone can help me out with a calculation.

Say I have a coordinates for a bounding box, for example as a viewport returned from Google Places API, e.g.

```
 "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
              "lng" : -122.0829009197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
              "lng" : -122.0855988802915
           }
        }
```

I'm then using these to return results from Elasticsearch filtering by locations within a Geo Bounding Box: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query.html

This is fine, however i'd like run a calculation to increase this viewport by, for example, 5 miles with the return value being another bounding box of increased size.

I guess the diagonal line running through the viewport would need to be increased by 2.5 miles each way, but I'm not sure on the calculation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this can be solved using Vicenty's formulae: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Direct_Problem).

JavaScript implementation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/geodesy for anyone interested.

Praise Vicenty.